# Some CGI scripts won't run

Tags: apache, shell, cgi

I'm getting a 500 error on some of my CGI scripts, but not others. Not exactly sure whats causing the issue, some assistance would be appreciated.

/var/log/apache2/errors.log

```
[Tue Oct 20 06:12:38.436646 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 12492] [client 65.162.40.26:27886] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/home/rawr/development/hivecontrol/ark/startserver.sh' failed, r$
[Tue Oct 20 06:12:38.437968 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 12492] [client 65.162.40.26:27886] End of script output before headers: startserver.sh, referer: http://arkcontrol.servegame.com/
```

Works - messageserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Content-type: text/html
echo 

message=$(echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*message=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g")
message=${message//+/ }
messageserver $message

echo "<HTML>"
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='1; url=../'>"
echo "</HTML>"
```

Does not work - startserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Content-type: text/html
echo 

ark_pid=$(pgrep ShooterGame)
output=$(ls -l /proc/$ark_pid/exe)

echo "<HTML>"

if [[ $output == *ark2* ]];
then
        echo "Server is already running"
else
        echo "Server didn't appear to be running"
        #startark
fi

echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='1; url=../'>"
echo "</HTML>"
```

File permissions

```
rawr@ubuntu:~/development/hivecontrol/ark$ ls -l
total 20
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rawr rawr 1544 Oct 20 04:10 index.html
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rawr rawr  357 Oct 20 05:50 killserver.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rawr rawr  272 Oct 20 05:12 messageserver.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rawr rawr  278 Oct 20 04:38 restartserver.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rawr rawr  369 Oct 20 05:56 startserver.sh
```

Comment: Remove ls error output with `output=$(ls -l /proc/$ark_pid/exe 2>/dev/null)` and debug with `echo "Output=${output}"`

Comment: also, does the httpd configuration file allows execution of CGI scripts in the directory where this script is? Is the Option ExecCGI listed there?

Comment: It was a permission issue. Easiest way I solved was by giving the www-data group ownership.

Answer (score 0):

The script is ok. You were probably mistaking the ls output for an error.
You just need to fix that if statement:

```
output=$(find /proc/$ark_pid/exe -maxdepth 1 -name '*ark2*')
...
if [[ -n $output ]]
...
```